# (Debug) Error In Xamarin App Development (Visual Studio)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

### The Basics

So I've been working with Xamarin a decent bit recently, and am looking for a solution to a current problem. I've been using the WoWonder script recently, and launched it on a site. i can confirm that the site is working well, without any hiccups. Although I've reworked some of the UI / UX, and basic functionality, I haven't delved extremely deep into it.

I'm currently using the Mobile Timeline applications to link into the network. I've had to debug a decent amount of problems so far with the NuGet packages, syntax errors, as well as authentication / decryption errors. I solved the first two, and solved the last by switching the SSL & TLS options in the Android Options area.

---

I would normally seek help from the author of said project, but given people in the comments haven't always gotten their answers, and instead got the runaround (Not to mention the broken english), I thought Stack would be the better option.

So far, I've asked around, and looked around, but haven't found anything. This is my last attempt before I start breaking everything down, line-by-line. I haven't found anyone else having a similar problem, other than the Xamarin > WP8 issue.

---

#### The Problem

Screenshots:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aub_kvZQCqk8ii7fW8ntcn4dxh-W 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aub_kvZQCqk8ii9Ksd86tPIHLXMo

---

SideNote: The project does use 'Xamarin Components," and the syntax / order of things is a mess. It's nothing that breaks anything or issues too many warnings, it just parses a lot that it can't find, or isn't relevant / needed / is outdated.

---

### Edit:

It's difficult to copy the context of the error in the emulator, since it doesn't seem to be showing up in visual studio. I'll transcribe it below.

Code Snippet:

```
System.Net.HttpRequestException: 500 (Internal Server Error) at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()[0x0002a] in <dcbf7ae3bce147228fa58d5bc31257ae>:0 at WowonderPhone.MainPage+<OnLoginClicked>d_2.MoveNext()[0x00252] in <1284583bda884ff38ca175979b310f47>:0
```

Comment: do NOT post errors as images.  Take the time to paste and format the error message as text.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: a 500 is a server error.  You need to look at your server logs to see what the underlying issue is.

Comment: I had thought about that, but given that it's a relatively 'plug 'n play' setup with the script, it just didn't seem likely. Nonetheless, what would be the first thing to check, Apache logs? I'm running a LAMP stack, on this anyway.

Comment: yes, the Apache or PHP logs

Comment: I pulled the Apache logs, and while there is something in the error log, the referenced time is yesterday, and I just tested it a few hours ago. Anyway, the access logs aren't showing any irregularities that I can see, but I may be overlooking it.
The error log described a conflict of SSL hostnames, followed by stating there's no SSL setup (although there is).
Should I post the contents of both here?

Comment: I would check with the authors of the script about how to track down the error.  Based on what you've posted this does sound like its a Xamarin issue.

Comment: If it helps, I found this in the access logs. There were no corresponding errors thrown though.  

    [17/May/2018:12:00:54 -0400] "POST //app_api.php?application=phone&type=get_settings HTTP/1.1" 500 4568 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; Android SDK built for x86 Build/NYC)"

Comment: have you used POSTMAN or a similar tool to test that the request you are generating is valid?

Comment: I haven't, how would I go about that? My working theory was that it looks like it was trying to do so over HTTP & TLS 1.1 (Correct me if I'm wrong). Given that my server forces SSL & TLS 1.2+, denying any others, I'm assuming there could be a conflict there? I appreciate all the help thus far.

Comment: if your server were denying the request you would get a different exception or status code, not a 500.  500 means it's processing the request and something went wrong internally.  Try downloading POSTMAN (or a similar tool) and see if you can sucessfully POST your request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This has since been fixed. It was a problem on the server side, but had to do with the script, as the person previously mentioned. It wasn't a problem with Apache directives, or heightened security, just an inconsistency in the script syntax. Unfortunately, since another person solved this directly, I don't know the exact margin of error.